# Using Set::extract to filter part of a dataset

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a query to find Homes from a database, along with some extra data from related tables, as follows:

```
$homes_data = $this->Home->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>$conditions,
    'order'=>array('Home.mls_status ASC','Home.num DESC'),
    'contain'=>array('Realtor.show_price','Realtor.show_address','HighlightImage.num')
))
```

At this point, I'd like to be able to use Set::extract to filter my resultset to remove any results where the MLS number is not valid, which in this case means is not exactly 6 numeric digits:

```
$homes_data = Set::extract('/Home/[mls=/^[[:digit:]]{6}$/]', $homes_data);
```

The problem with this is that it's losing the Realtor and HighlightImage results of the array.  So:

Is there a simple way of recasting this, to keep the associated data for homes with a valid MLS?

Failing this, is there a way to work the condition "must be numeric and exactly 6 digits in length" into the SQL query, preferably while keeping it within the realms of tidy, idiomatic CakePHP?

Comment: Can't you filter it in the query, in your $conditions?

Comment: @kaklon - Could be a good idea.  I'm not 100% sure yet how to phrase it in CakePHP speak.  Or indeed in MySQL!

Comment: Hmm, in MySQL: select mls from homes where mls regexp '^[[:digit:]]{6}$'; works.  Maybe I can pass that to Cake without too much pain...

Comment: Sweet, I think adding 'mls REGEXP'=>'^[[:digit:]]{6}$' to the conditions array will do what I need, at least for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thesunneversets,

if validation during data entry is not an option, maybe writing a customized model function is indicated to keep your controller thin.
You should be able to set up the validation rules for the model and use validation manually in this customized function.

**Edit0:**
Another approach could be to map the existing data to your favorite set of values.

Comment: Unfortunately, for reasons obscure to me, it seems to have been considered desirable at some point for people to put non-numeric data in the mls field (e.g. 'exclude' or whatever).  I'm sure you're right that a better design would be for valid numbers only to be contained in this field, but for the time being I may be stuck with checking the data after it comes out of the database.  I'll definitely look into the possibility of sanitizing the contents of this field, and not letting nonsense into it in future, though; good idea!